# Reload components list

Tags: common-lisp, asdf

Here is my workflow: I have a running REPL in my emacs and I create a new system. When I try to test the system with `(asdf:test-system :system)` I get a `Component :SYSTEM not found` error. Of course when I restart the lisp image the component is found.

My question is: **Can I signal to ASDF that there is a new system in the `~/common-lisp/` directory?**

I imagine the command I am looking for would be something like: `(asdf:reload-systems)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearing the configuration works when loading systems. Hopefully this also works for testing them:

```
* (asdf:load-system :test)

debugger invoked on a ASDF/FIND-SYSTEM:MISSING-COMPONENT in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1001E0E533}>:
  Component :TEST not found

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [RETRY                        ] Retry ASDF operation.
  1: [CLEAR-CONFIGURATION-AND-RETRY] Retry ASDF operation after resetting the
                                     configuration.
  2: [ABORT                        ] Exit debugger, returning to top level.

((:METHOD ASDF/OPERATE:OPERATE (SYMBOL T)) ASDF/LISP-ACTION:LOAD-OP :TEST) [fast-method]
0]
```

Using restart *#1* makes it work here. But you can also do it yourself:

```
* (asdf:clear-configuration)

NIL
* (asdf:load-system :test)

T
*
```

Note that the `~/common-lisp/` path is supported by default only from ASDF 3.1.2, you might need to check which version is yours.

For details [see the documentation](https://common-lisp.net/project/asdf/asdf.html).

Comment: Tested both the restart and the `clear-configuration` function and it works. Thanks. I am not sure why the restart didn't work the first time I tried it.

Comment: @tsikov If that happens again, try to check if anything is unusual. E.g. sometimes I make changes in Emacs but forget to save a buffer.